# tee command in C with option

Tags: c, command, tee

I have command tee in C, and I should add option -a which :supports the -a option file, which results in adding the data being read to the end of the file, if available.  Anyone could help?
 I try put inside :

```
if ( (option = getopt(argc,argv,"a")) != -1 ){
           switch (option){
           case 'a':
```

But I don't know what next.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]){

FILE *fp, *fp1;
char buffer;

if(argc != 4){
printf("\nError");
printf("\nSintaxis: tee [archivo1] [archivo2]\n");
exit(0);
}

if(strcmp(argv[1], "tee") == 0){
fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
fp1 = fopen(argv[3], "w");

printf("\Content in %s:\n", argv[2]);

while(!feof(fp)){
    buffer = fgetc(fp);
    fputc(buffer, fp1);
    printf("%c", buffer);
}

printf("\n\n%s received %s\n", argv[3], argv[2]);   

fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);
}
else
    printf("\nThe first argument have to be tee\n");
}
```

Second version , I think better.
 But if I run program without option -a else if (argc == 2) {
      printf("Write to file: %s\n", argv[1]);
      process_save_reading(argv[1],"w+") write some text in file argv[1] -file is empty

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void usage() {
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: [-a program]");
exit(1);
}

void err(char * s1, char * s2) {
fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s ", s1);
perror(s2);
exit(1);
}
void process_reading() {
int c = fgetc(stdin);
while (c != EOF) {
putchar(c);
c = getchar();
}
}

void write_file_content(char * filename, int cnt, const char* mode) {
FILE *fp;
if ((fp = fopen(filename, mode)) == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Can not open file: %s\n", filename);
exit(1);
}
fputc(cnt, fp);
fclose (fp);
}

void process_save_reading(char * filename, const char* mode) {
int c = fgetc(stdin);
while (c != EOF) {
putchar(c);
write_file_content(filename, c, mode);
c = getchar();
}
}

int file_exists(char * filename) {
return access(filename, F_OK) != -1;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
char * opts = "a:";
int c;

if (argc == 1) {
process_reading();
}
else if (argc == 2) {
printf("Write to file: %s\n", argv[1]);
process_save_reading(argv[1],"w+");
} 
else {
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, opts)) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
            if (!file_exists(optarg)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "File: '%s' doesn't exists\n", optarg);
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("Save to file: %s\n", optarg);
            process_save_reading(optarg,"a+");
```

Comment: You *have* read e.g. [the `getopt(3)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)? It has an example to show you how to use it.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not do `while(!feof(...))` because it will not work as you expect it to. The `EOF` flag is not set until *after* you read from beyond the end of the file, meaning your loop will iterate once to many. And as you don't check the value returned from [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) you will not notice that. Also note that [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an *`int`*.

Comment: ok I add   'fp1 = fopen(argv[3], "a+")' and results in adding the data being read to the end of the file, but i stil can't add option -a

Comment: And what if the user does `-afilename`? ***Read*** the manual page, read what the prefix `":"` does when specifying an argument, read what `optarg` is, read (and try out) the example.

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I meant the `":"` *suffix*.